# Dynamic searching in tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, nspredicate

I've a `tableview` and text field where I've implemented search method. Right now, when I write some value in `textfield` and click search button, then it search in the `tableview`. But, I want it to be dynamic means the moment I start typing in `textfield` it should start searching without clicking any `button`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Connect this method on `Editing Changed Event` of your `TextField`. So, this method is called when you are changing its value.

```
- (IBAction)txtValueChanged:(UITextField)sender
{
    [self dynamicSearchInto:sender.text];
    //From here, we are passing text of textField.
}
```

Here, `allData` is an `array` which contains all your data. And `searchArray` is an array in which contains only searching data. So make sure that, you have to set count of `searchArray` into `tableview's` rows count. And setting data into tableview according to this `searchArray`.

```
-(void)dynamicSearchInto:(NSString *)strText
{
    if (strText.length != 0)
    {
        searchArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
        NSString *str=txtSearch.text;
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['yourKey'] contains[c] %@", str];
        searchArray = [allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        [myTableView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        searchArray = allData;
    }
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me.

Answer (score 3):

To implement dynamic search in the ios, we can also use textbox as search bar.

Go to StoryBoard and do the following changes

1. Add the textbox to the view controller and assign the outlets and delegates.
2. now to viewcontroller.m and paste the following code

```html
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    searchTextString=textField.text;

    [self updateSearchArray:searchTextString];
}


-(void)updateSearchArray:(NSString *)searchText
{
    
    if(searchText.length==0)
   {
        isFilter=NO;    }
    else{
      
       isFilter=YES;
        
       searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        
        for(NSString *string in responceArray){

        NSRange stringRange = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string]
                               rangeOfString:searchtext.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            
        if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [searchArray addObject:string];

        }
            
        }
        
        [jobsTable reloadData];
    }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Connect method that do the same as on click to the event Value changed (see in the screenshot at the very bottom) in connections inspector.

[image]

Comment: @NileshJha if my answer solved your problem - could you, please, accept it (it may be helpful to others people)?