# Getting Wrong id from NSMutableArray in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xml-parsing

I'm new in iOS and when I add search box in my textbox after searching it give me the wrong id. In my code there is three array one is for id another is for name and third one  is to search.

**My code:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sections{
    if(tableView == table)
    {
        if(isFilter)
        {
            return [searchArray count];
        }
        else
        return [idarray count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == table)
    {
        if(isFilter)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[namearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        if(tableView == table)
        {
            if(isFilter)
            {
                txt.text=[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                table.hidden=YES;
                txt.enabled=NO;
                txt.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[namearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                idlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                EmployeeID=idlbl.text;
                EmployeeName=txt.text;

            }
            else
            {
                txt.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[namearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                idlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                table.hidden=YES;
                EmployeeID=idlbl.text;
                EmployeeName=txt.text;
                txt.enabled=NO;
            }

        }
}

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    searchTextString=textField.text;
    [self updateSearchArray:searchTextString];
}
-(void)updateSearchArray:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchText.length==0)
    {
        isFilter=NO;
    }
    else{

        isFilter=YES;
        searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(NSString *string in namearray){

            NSRange stringRange=[string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(stringRange.location !=NSNotFound){

                [searchArray addObject:string];
            }
        }
        [table reloadData];}
}
```

I'm getting the EmployeeID as 1 where EmployeeID is 18 It is taking the value which is in the table not taking the value of id array. I'm using if(tableview == table) because there is more then one table in one view controller.
[image]
It is also updating the id. as shown in image
[image]

But I do not need to update the idarray. My question is how can I get Value of array it is giving me an indexpath of tableview cell Any Suggetion
 Thanks in Advance!

Comment: in your didselectRowAtIndexPath method you have compare your array   for (int i1=0 ; i1<[YOURORIGNALARRAY count]; i1++) {
                if ([SEARCHARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]==[[YOURORIGNALARRAY valueForKey:@"YOURKEY"] objectAtIndex:i1]) {
                
 }
            }

Comment: 1. It will be cleaner to have an `NSArray *` for use by the tableview and have that point to the *normal* or *search* arrays depending on whether you are searching or not; this will remove the need for the `if (isFilter)` conditions.  2.  Have you made sure the model arrays contain the correct data? 3. How can the name array be the same size as the normal array and the filtered array?

Comment: @himanshu why I am getting idarray as 1 while it is 18.

Comment: Did u show me your array that orignal one and  your search array.

Comment: @himanshu yes..

Comment: @Muju show me your array value .

Comment: @himanshu idarray is Printing description of self->idarray:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
11,
12,
13,
14,
15,
16,
17,
18,
)

Comment: Did u create a 2 array for a single person information like name have one array id have different array and id have connected with name

Comment: @himanshu name have one array, id have one array and search have one array.

Comment: then simply create one array with key pair value like .  YOURARRAY_NAME =@[@{@"id":@"1" , @"name":@"employee name"},
                         @{@"id":@"2" , @"name":@"employee name 2"}}];

Comment: @Himanshu I created Dictionary in the same way as you suggest.

Comment: and when you want perform searching in this array then use NSString *searchTerm = @"search this";
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE[cd] %@", searchTerm];
 NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];  and use filter array

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I have change question.

Comment: @Droppy I have change question please see it.

Comment: use my array your problem will be slove

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya where to add your code in my code.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Your Code dosen't search anything.I am searching in dynamic array.

Comment: @user3182143 Please see the updated question.

Comment: i just tell you that make your dynamic array that i build in comment. and after it perform searching,

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya OK

Comment: NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
    FILETERARRAY = [[YOUROLDARRAY valueForKey:@"ARRAYSEARCHKEY"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
    if (FILETERARRAY.count == 0) {
        searchformember=0;
        [self.tbl_select_members reloadData];
       
    } [self.tbl_select_members reloadData];

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Your code is not working.

Comment: I just use this code in project and its complete working.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I am using two array is that is a problem.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya idarray give me the index tableview cell. But i need value of array my code now is  idlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: but why you use 2 array perform with single array give me your email id i give you one demo check it

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I need it's id to pass in another JSON link.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  mujtabaulhasankhan@rediffmail.com

Comment: check that demo i create long time ago if any misunderstanding in that send me replay in my mail

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Can you send your email on this mujtabaulhasankhan@gmail.com . I didn't get your mail.

Comment: @Muju idArray is not been filtered with name array . so obviosly its gonna give you wrong id . For example : In name array before filtering, at Index 0 there is "a" . you search for "b". now at index 0 its "b" . but in your id array at index 0 its representing "a" reference .

Comment: From my point of view you should create dictionary not different array .

Comment: @DevangGoswami But table view get crash if I add dictionary in it.

Comment: @Muju its fail to send  and now i try again wait

Comment: @Muju check your mail account mujtabaulhasankhan@gmail.com this one i just send you one demo

Comment: @Muju your coding style is too poor improve it with your logic brother you send me that domo i just give you down vote .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get actual value of NSMutableArray not Index in UITableview in Objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036478/how-to-get-actual-value-of-nsmutablearray-not-index-in-uitableview-in-objective)

Answer (score 0):

When i used to work on the search bar button in my app, i too got same problem , but i have created the textbox which is acting as search bar.

i thought it will be work fine for you also, Happy Coding.......

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209175/dynamic-searching-in-tableview-in-ios/39386792#39386792)

Comment: I am using a same code. But the problem is that this code has only name but my array has name as well as id. It is dictionary.

Comment: my ID Array also get updated when I search from 18 to 1

Answer (score 0):

Check this file for create one array and perform searching on that array with NSPredicate

https://gist.github.com/himanshu-benzatine/716fd8d7ca035a5c0a01c87df48915bf